# Filter data in the same minute

Tags: sql, postgresql

For a table like this, I want to be able to filter out older data that happens in the same minute.

```
| time                | data |  
| ------------------- | ---- |  
| 2020-12-01 10:00:05 | a    |  
| 2020-12-01 10:00:05 | b    | 
| 2020-12-01 10:00:32 | c    |  
| 2020-12-01 10:00:32 | d    | 
| 2020-12-01 10:01:21 | e    |  
| 2020-12-01 10:01:21 | f    |  
| 2020-12-01 10:01:52 | g    |  
| 2020-12-01 10:01:52 | h    |
```

After querying I want to get a result like this

```
| time                | data |  
| ------------------- | ---- |  
| 2020-12-01 10:00:32 | c    |  
| 2020-12-01 10:00:32 | d    |  
| 2020-12-01 10:01:52 | g    |  
| 2020-12-01 10:00:52 | h    |
```

Basically the latest data set for a particular minute.
I am using a PostgreSQL database.

Comment: Please reformat using to make the data readable.

Comment: can you explain why you got both c and d with the same "time" value

Answer (score 1):

You may use `DISTINCT ON` here:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (TO_CHAR(time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI')) time, data
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY TO_CHAR(time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI'), time DESC;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

**Edit:**

Given that you have revealed there might be duplicates, and in that case you would want to retain all of them, we can't use `DISTINCT ON`.  Instead, use `RANK` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY TO_CHAR(time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI')
                           ORDER BY time DESC) rnk
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT time, data
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

### Demo

Comment: Hi Tim, I have edited the dataset. The original dataset did not properly reflect my true intentions. 
Don't think DISTINCT ON would work here since there are more than one rows for the same time. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: @StevenJohnLally I have edited my answer.  Just a friendly reminder that you should _not_ dramatically change your question after other users have answered.  Doing so runs the risk of _invalidating_ those other helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use date_trunc('minute', time) instead of to_char() in the query that @TimBiegelesien shared with you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table t
 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
         (SELECT 1 FROM your_table tt
           WHERE date_trunc('minute', tt.time) = date_trunc('minute', t.time)
             and tt.time > t.time)
```